# ASP.NET 5 (vNext) Environment Tag Helper From Code

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core-mvc, tag-helpers

I'm trying to determine how to get the functionalty of this tag helper in any class file:

```
<environment names="Development"> </environment>
```

I understand that environment information is available via an **IHostingEnvironment** object, but I'm not sure how to grab it without dependency injection.

Is it possible to get DI registered service implementations from any class?

In this specific case, I'm writing some HtmlHelper extension methods, but I think the question applies in a broader sense.

Comment: To help you better, why do you want to do this without relying on dependency injection?

Answer (score 1):

So, from inside of an IHtmlHelper extension method, this works:

```
IHostingEnvironment env = HtmlHelper.ViewContext.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetService(typeof(IHostingEnvironment)) as IHostingEnvironment;
```

Is there a more generic way to grab a service instance without relying on dependency injection?

Comment: If you are extending an HtmlHelper, this is totally a valid way to do it. Just be careful of what you are using. `RequestServices` are scoped for the current request and `ApplicationServices` are scoped for the lifetime of the application. :)